# bootstrap 4 anchor tags breaks columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with bootstrap 4, this works perfectly in bootstrap 3.

when i am adding a link between 3 or more columns, it puts the cols on another line instead of inline.

how do you stop bootstrap 4 from breaking cols when a a tag is in the row.

is there a way to get around this issue?

https://codepen.io/wobstyr/pen/NJdyeR

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row border">
      <a href="page1.html">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Happy</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Gilmore</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">1987</div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3"><a href="delete.html">icon</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border">
      <a href="page1.html">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Happy</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Gilmore</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">1987</div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3"><a href="delete.html">icon</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border">
      <a href="page1.html">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Happy</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Gilmore</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">1987</div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3"><a href="delete.html">icon</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border">
      <a href="page1.html">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Happy</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Gilmore</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">1987</div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3"><a href="delete.html">icon</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border">
      <a href="page1.html">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Happy</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">Gilmore</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">1987</div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3"><a href="delete.html">icon</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```